How to deploy only updated resources in API Gateway using Terraform without triggering a full redeployment?
I have deployed a solution for API Gateway using Terraform. To address the issue of changes to a Swagger file not being deployed correctly, I introduced a dynamic value (description = ${timestamp}) in the stage resource.
While this approach solves the deployment issue, it has an unwanted side effect: every time I apply changes, all the API Gateway resources (about 200 APIs) get redeployed.
The team has now requested to make the Terraform plan more readable and to limit deployments to only the resources that have been updated, avoiding a complete redeployment of all APIs.
What is the best way to achieve this in Terraform? How can I avoid triggering a full redeployment while still ensuring updates to the Swagger file are applied correctly?
I want to redeploy only the swagger file that was updated and read during, terraform plan, "Resource xxxx will be updated".
Thanks for your help
Update: The solution that I find out is to use this type of description:
resource "aws_api_gateway_stage" "dev" {
  count = var.dev_create_deployment ? 1 : 0

  deployment_id = aws_api_gateway_deployment.dev["0"].id
  rest_api_id   = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.this.id
  stage_name    = var.dev_stage_name
  variables     = var.dev_stage_variables

  description = "Deployed at ${filesha256(var.swagger)}"

I used the hash of the Swagger file, which changes every time modifications are made to the Swagger. This way, if I modify 3 Swagger files, only those 3 will have a different hash, not all 200.
I need to close this question or I need to something else? I want to help other people with same problem.

Did you try to add the file for that swagger as a hash code trigger to that api resource?
Below is an example on how to use it, this will make sure that, the specific api_gateway_deployment will only be triggered, when the file by itself get changed, and nothing else should be referenced by that change
data "local_file" "swagger_file" {
  filename = "${path.module}/swagger.json"
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_deployment" "api_deployment" {
  rest_api_id = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.example.id
  stage_name  = "prod"

  triggers = {
    swagger_hash = md5(data.local_file.swagger_file.content)
  }
}


Hi, thanks your your answer, I have implemented this flow in my code
resource "aws_api_gateway_deployment" "dev" {
rest_api_id = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.this.id
triggers = {
redeployment = sha1(jsonencode([
aws_api_gateway_rest_api.this.body,
data.aws_iam_policy_document.this
]))
}
lifecycle {
create_before_destroy = true
}
depends_on = [
aws_api_gateway_rest_api_policy.this
]
}
resource "aws_api_gateway_stage" "dev" {
count = var.dev_create_deployment ? 1 : 0
//stuff
description = "Deployed at ${filesha256(var.swagger)}"

I don't know if is correct, but now I will try to deploy this code with md5 of swagger in the description
